# MySQL foreign key constraints, cascade delete

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, innodb

I want to use foreign keys to keep the integrity and avoid orphans (I already use innoDB).

How do I make a SQL statment that DELETE ON CASCADE?

If I delete a category then how do I make sure that it would not delete products that also are related to other categories.

The pivot table "categories_products" creates a many-to-many relationship between the two other tables.

```
categories
- id (INT)
- name (VARCHAR 255)

products
- id
- name
- price

categories_products
- categories_id
- products_id
```

Comment: Hi - you might want to modify the question title, it's about cascade deletes really, not specifically pivot tables.

Answer (score 419, accepted):

If your cascading deletes nuke a product because it was a member of a category that was killed, then you've set up your foreign keys improperly. Given your example tables, you should have the following table setup:

```
CREATE TABLE categories (
    id int unsigned not null primary key,
    name VARCHAR(255) default null
)Engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE products (
    id int unsigned not null primary key,
    name VARCHAR(255) default null
)Engine=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE categories_products (
    category_id int unsigned not null,
    product_id int unsigned not null,
    PRIMARY KEY (category_id, product_id),
    KEY pkey (product_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (category_id) REFERENCES categories (id)
       ON DELETE CASCADE
       ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products (id)
       ON DELETE CASCADE
       ON UPDATE CASCADE
)Engine=InnoDB;
```

This way, you can delete a product OR a category, and only the associated records in categories_products will die alongside. The cascade won't travel farther up the tree and delete the parent product/category table.

e.g.

```
products: boots, mittens, hats, coats
categories: red, green, blue, white, black

prod/cats: red boots, green mittens, red coats, black hats
```

If you delete the 'red' category, then only the 'red' entry in the categories table dies, as well as the two entries prod/cats: 'red boots' and 'red coats'.

The delete will not cascade any farther and will not take out the 'boots' and 'coats' categories.

comment followup:

you're still misunderstanding how cascaded deletes work. They only affect the tables in which the "on delete cascade" is defined. In this case, the cascade is set in the "categories_products" table. If you delete the 'red' category, the only records that will cascade delete in categories_products are those where `category_id = red`. It won't touch any records where 'category_id = blue', and it would not travel onwards to the "products" table, because there's no foreign key defined in that table.

Here's a more concrete example:

```
categories:     products:
+----+------+   +----+---------+
| id | name |   | id | name    |
+----+------+   +----+---------+
| 1  | red  |   | 1  | mittens |
| 2  | blue |   | 2  | boots   |
+---++------+   +----+---------+

products_categories:
+------------+-------------+
| product_id | category_id |
+------------+-------------+
| 1          | 1           | // red mittens
| 1          | 2           | // blue mittens
| 2          | 1           | // red boots
| 2          | 2           | // blue boots
+------------+-------------+
```

Let's say you delete category #2 (blue):

```
DELETE FROM categories WHERE (id = 2);
```

the DBMS will look at all the tables which have a foreign key pointing at the 'categories' table, and delete the records where the matching id is 2. Since we only defined the foreign key relationship in `products_categories`, you end up with this table once the delete completes:

```
+------------+-------------+
| product_id | category_id |
+------------+-------------+
| 1          | 1           | // red mittens
| 2          | 1           | // red boots
+------------+-------------+
```

There's no foreign key defined in the `products` table, so the cascade will not work there, so you've still got boots and mittens listed. There's just no 'blue boots' and no 'blue mittens' anymore.

Comment: I think I wrote my question the wrong way. If I delete a category then how do I make sure that it would not delete products that also are related to other categories.

Comment: This is a really great, highly perspicuous, and wonderfully illustrated answer.  Thanks for taking the time to write it all out.

Comment: When creating the tables, you need to specify InnoDB or another MySQL engine that's capable of `CASCADE` operations. Otherwise the MySQL default, MyISAM, will be used and MyISAM does not support `CASCADE` operations. To do this, just add `ENGINE InnoDB` before the last `;`.

Answer (score 12):

I got confused by the answer to this question, so I created a test case in MySQL, hope this helps

```
-- Schema
CREATE TABLE T1 (
    `ID` int not null auto_increment,
    `Label` varchar(50),
    primary key (`ID`)
);

CREATE TABLE T2 (
    `ID` int not null auto_increment,
    `Label` varchar(50),
    primary key (`ID`)
);

CREATE TABLE TT (
    `IDT1` int not null,
    `IDT2` int not null,
    primary key (`IDT1`,`IDT2`)
);

ALTER TABLE `TT`
    ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_tt_t1` FOREIGN KEY (`IDT1`) REFERENCES `T1`(`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_tt_t2` FOREIGN KEY (`IDT2`) REFERENCES `T2`(`ID`) ON DELETE CASCADE;

-- Data
INSERT INTO `T1` (`Label`) VALUES ('T1V1'),('T1V2'),('T1V3'),('T1V4');
INSERT INTO `T2` (`Label`) VALUES ('T2V1'),('T2V2'),('T2V3'),('T2V4');
INSERT INTO `TT` (`IDT1`,`IDT2`) VALUES
(1,1),(1,2),(1,3),(1,4),
(2,1),(2,2),(2,3),(2,4),
(3,1),(3,2),(3,3),(3,4),
(4,1),(4,2),(4,3),(4,4);

-- Delete
DELETE FROM `T2` WHERE `ID`=4; -- Delete one field, all the associated fields on tt, will be deleted, no change in T1
TRUNCATE `T2`; -- Can't truncate a table with a referenced field
DELETE FROM `T2`; -- This will do the job, delete all fields from T2, and all associations from TT, no change in T1
```

Answer (score 8):

I think (I'm not certain) that foreign key constraints won't do precisely what you want given your table design. Perhaps the best thing to do is to define a stored procedure that will delete a category the way you want, and then call that procedure whenever you want to delete a category.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `DeleteCategory` (IN category_ID INT)
LANGUAGE SQL
NOT DETERMINISTIC
MODIFIES SQL DATA
SQL SECURITY DEFINER
BEGIN

DELETE FROM
    `products`
WHERE
    `id` IN (
        SELECT `products_id`
        FROM `categories_products`
        WHERE `categories_id` = category_ID
    )
;

DELETE FROM `categories`
WHERE `id` = category_ID;

END
```

You also need to add the following foreign key constraints to the linking table:

```
ALTER TABLE `categories_products` ADD
    CONSTRAINT `Constr_categoriesproducts_categories_fk`
    FOREIGN KEY `categories_fk` (`categories_id`) REFERENCES `categories` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT `Constr_categoriesproducts_products_fk`
    FOREIGN KEY `products_fk` (`products_id`) REFERENCES `products` (`id`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

The CONSTRAINT clause can, of course, also appear in the CREATE TABLE statement.

Having created these schema objects, you can delete a category and get the behaviour you want by issuing `CALL DeleteCategory(category_ID)` (where category_ID is the category to be deleted), and it will behave how you want. But don't issue a normal `DELETE FROM` query, unless you want more standard behaviour (i.e. delete from the linking table only, and leave the `products` table alone).

Comment: I think I wrote my question the wrong way. If I delete a category then how do I make sure that it would not delete products that also are related to other categories.

Comment: ok well in that case I think Marc B's answer does what you want.

Comment: Hello @Hammerite, can you please tell me what is the meaning of `KEY pkey (product_id),` in the third `CREATE TABLE` query in accepted answer?