# MySQL triggered delete

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have 2 tables:

```
User (id, user, pass, ...)

Post (user_id, post, ...)
```

I would like to create a trigger which delete post of a user, before deleting user... Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the tables is  `innodb` engine

you can use

```
ON DELETE CASCADE
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

look an example here :

[MySQL foreign key constraints, cascade delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914936/mysql-foreign-key-constraints-cascade-delete)

Answer (score 0):

Use a [stored procedure](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/getting-started-with-mysql-stored-procedures.aspx)