# Undesirable delete in a many to many relationship in MySql

Tags: mysql, hibernate, many-to-many, cascading-deletes

There is a similare question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914936/mysql-foreign-key-constraints-cascade-delete/2917374#2917374) but It didn't help

I have a classic many to many relationship between `Organisme` | `Organisme_groupe` | `Groupe`.

I want to keep `Organisme` when deleting `Groupe` and vice-versa. 
Actually if I delete Organisme, the attached Groupe is deleted also.

I'am little confused, because from what I understand, the cascade action wouldn't go farther than the child table (which is the intermediate table here).

Organisme

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `organisme` (
  `ORGANISME_ID` int(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,  
  `TYPE_ORGANISME` varchar(128) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `NAME` varchar(80) DEFAULT ''  
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Groupe

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `groupe` (
  `GROUPE_ID` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
  `NAME_GROUPE` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''  
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Organisme_groupe

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS  `organisme_groupe`(
      `ORGANISME_ID` int(10) NOT NULL,
      `GROUPE_ID` int(10) NOT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY (ORGANISME_ID, GROUPE_ID)
    )ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

The constraints

```
ALTER TABLE `organisme_groupe`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_organisme_groupe_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ORGANISME_ID`) REFERENCES `organisme` (`ORGANISME_ID`)  ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_organisme_groupe_2` FOREIGN KEY (`GROUPE_ID`) REFERENCES `groupe` (`GROUPE_ID`)  ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: Do you mean: When delete `organisme`, delete `organisme_groupe`, but keep `groupe`. When delete `groupe`, delete `organisme_groupe`, but keep `organisme`.

Comment: Your understanding is correct. Your schema definition is correct. This should work as you've stated, identical to the situation in the question to which you've linked. Can you show us the query deleting an Organisme which is also deleting some Groupes?

Comment: @JohnWoo but the intermediate table would keep ids of deleted organismes/groupes.

Comment: @Moh: You're contradicting yourself. Is mikespook entirely correct or not? Could you specify the behavior you want and the behavior you see in the same form as mikespook's comment?

Comment: @mikespook, yes that exactly what I'am looking for

Comment: @aib when I checked the code that delete Organisme I stumbled upon a Cascade annotation from hibernate, when it's removed, it worked as I wanted... I didn't know actually that Hibernate can override MySql setting... I should also update the tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySql mapping was coorect, the problem was that I was adding the Cascading annotation in the Hibernate model which seems to override the MySQL constraints