# MySQL Foreign Constraint ON DELETE CASCADE

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, cascade

I Want to know if I implemented it right or if it is the other way around.

So I have 3 tables:

`TableParent`, `TableChild` and `AnotherTable`

`TableParent` has a PK called `id`

`TableChild` and `AnotherTable` has a PK also called `id` that is also a FK Constraint to `TableParent.id` and it has `ON DELETE CASCADE`

I modeled it thinking that if I delete a row in `TableParent`, every row in `TableChild` and `AnotherTable` will be auto deleted.

Does it works that way?  (Using MySQL, engine InnoDB)

Comment: Yes is too short. - The real question is do you want it to work that way.  Is there a need to keep history of child/parent. If no historical needs, or your managing history a different way then yes this works. But lets say AnotherTable is sales data related to the item data in the parent table and pricing data in the child table.   If you delete the item, you also delete price history and sales data.  So is the design you want?

Comment: Yeah, I'm managing that way cause I'm subclassing tables, using the Class Table Inheritance (http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html). The example on the post is not the real, it's adapted to fill the question. I just tested it and yep, it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Was going to post this in a comment, but the comment button is not showing up.

Check out this quesion/answer.  I think it has all you need and more on this issue.

[MySQL foreign key constraints, cascade delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914936/mysql-foreign-key-constraints-cascade-delete?rq=1)

I could retype it all, but that seems redundent.