# How do I delete row with primary key using foreign key from other table?

Tags: php, mysql, foreign-keys, sql-delete

I have a table called 'agenda' //translation: dairy

with the following rows:

```
idagenda // primary key
title
waar
organisatie
...
etc.
...
```

I also have a table for the date of an diary item/event called agendadatum

with the following rows:

```
id // primary key
idagenda // id from other table
van //from
tot // till
datum // date
```

When the field 'tot' is the date from Today it will delete the rows from the database, but the rows in the 'agenda' table remain untouched. They're not deleted, because I did not call them.

My delete query looks like this:

```
DELETE FROM agendadatum WHERE tot < NOW();
```

How can I also delete the rows from 'agenda' table, that have the same id then the foreign key in agendadatum?

Comment: I understand you want to delete a whole agenda when it contains *any* entry whose `tot` date is past, am I right?

Comment: currently, I am deleting only the row from agendadatum where the field `tot` = NOW(); as you can see, this table has an idagenda from the other table. I use joins to show them on 1 page. I don't know how to delete both rows. not only from agendadatum but from agenda too. So I only want to delete the row that has the same id then the foreign key from agendadatum.

Comment: But this will also delete `agenda`'s having several `agendadatum` entries, and possibly some with a `tot` date in the future. Are you okay with this?

Comment: No it won't. my table is called agenda, it has field like id, title, organisation etc. the id from that table is the same as the `idagenda` in my agendadatum table. If I delete the agendadatum row, I would like to delete the one with the idagenda the same as the one from agendadatum to be deleted also.

Comment: Imagine you have an Agenda with (agendaid = 1), and two Agendadatum like (id = 1, agendaid = 1, tot = '2012') and (id = 2, agendaid = 1, tot = '2014'). The first agendadatum matches your criteria, then Agenda [1] should be deleted, leaving agendadatum [2] orphaned.

Comment: The agendadatum is the second table, so If I insert into agenda and add datums they always ahve the insert_id from the agenda table :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36022/discussion-between-randomseed-and-kees-sonnema)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can delete from multiple tables in one query:

```
DELETE agenda.*, agendadatum.*
FROM agenda
JOIN agendadatum USING (idagenda)
WHERE tot < NOW();
```

This will delete rows from both agenda and agendadatum, and only those rows matching the conditions (same rows as returned by the query if you replaced `DELETE` with `SELECT`).

Comment: Wow didn't knew about `USING` will try this :D

Comment: This is just a syntactic shortcut for `ON t1.field = t2.field` when both fields have the same name. Handy, nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

In your create table you need to mention the Foreign Key Constraint like

```
FOREIGN KEY (product_id) REFERENCES products (id)
       ON DELETE CASCADE
       ON UPDATE CASCADE,
```

**and after that If you run the delete query, automatically the rows will be deleted, which is referencing the ids of the table**

You can go through the explanation present in [delete on cascade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914936/mysql-foreign-key-constraints-cascade-delete)

Comment: How can I do this in phpmyadmin relation view? and could you also use my units?

Comment: I have this, but it's giving an error: `FOREIGN KEY (idagenda) REFERENCES agenda (idagenda)
     ON DELETE CASCADE,
     ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 DELETE FROM agendadatum WHERE tot < NOW();`

Comment: @KeesSonnema This was an example of how you would define the foreign key on `agenda`. Either recreate your table or modify it it with [`ALTER TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/alter-table.html).

Comment: could you give an alter table example, because I can't find that anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using php you can try the following

```
//get all agentadatum data with date now and before
$select_agendadatum = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM agendadatum WHERE tot <= NOW()") or die (mysql_error());
//loop through rows
while($row_agendadatum = mysql_fetch_assoc($select_agendadatum))
{
     //delete agendadatum row
     $delete_agendadatum = mysql_query("DELETE FROM agendadatum WHERE id = '".$row_agendadatum['id']."'") or die (mysql_error());
    //delete agenda row
    $delete_agenda= mysql_query("DELETE FROM agenda WHERE idagenda = '".$row_agendadatum['idagenda']."'") or die (mysql_error());
}
```

if your logic accepts more than one agendadatum per agenta you can simply count if there is more than 1 agendadatum in a specific agenta before deleting the agenta...

hope this helps

Comment: I'm not going to use mysql_* queries anymore. they're deprecated.

Comment: keep the logic and use mysqli_*

Comment: I don't have mysqli_* configured on my webhost.