# Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this foreign key:

```
ALTER TABLE `tags`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `file_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`file_id`) 
  REFERENCES `files` (`id`);
```

When I delete row in `files` and there are `tags` left associated with that file, I get `Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row` understandably. What should I do? Can I delete a file and then tags associated with it, or I need to remove tags first and then the file and there's just no other way?

EDIT: Just found out about `ON DELETE CASCADE`, so probably I should this instead, yeah?

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for an [ON CASCADE DELETE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) statement. A really good example is given on [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914936/mysql-foreign-key-constraints-cascade-delete)