# Deleting A specific table in msql

Tags: mysql

I would  like to create a trigger that will delete all database records from the **survey_responses** for a given **survey_responder** when delete a record from **survey_responder**.
In other words, when I delete a **survey_responder** I want to delete their responses from the database so that there are no orphan records. 
The thing is I keep getting an error. Any help?

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER delete_log AFTER DELETE on survey_responders
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
     delete * from survey_responses
     where survey_responders.id = survey_responses.survey_responder_id;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: why use a trigger? a foreign key with cascade delete would take care of it automatically.

Comment: I would keep it simple and use a foreign key with cascade delete.
This should help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914936/mysql-foreign-key-constraints-cascade-delete

Comment: I have been requested to use only triggers

Comment: what error do you have?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to remove * from delete query.