# how to cascade delete rows from three tables in mysql by referencing a relationship

Tags: php, mysql, cascading-deletes

```
DELETE f.* FROM FILE f, topic t, course c WHERE f.topic_id = t.topic_id AND t.course_id = 28;

DELETE t.* FROM topic t WHERE t.course_id = 28;

DELETE c.* FROM course c WHERE c.course_id = 28;
```

EDIT: The op wants to know (as indicated in the comments that clarified the question) that he would like to delete rows in all three tables where they share an id... essentially a cascading delete across three tables.

Comment: Explain your problem please.

Comment: So, what's the question here? didn't get that.

Comment: Welcome to SO! if you have constraints set up between the tables, you should be able to do a cascading delete. check this out. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914936/mysql-foreign-key-constraints-cascade-delete

Comment: You want to delete the reference across all tables right?

Comment: i want delete the course from table and at that time i want delete the course topics and topic files delete as well as

Comment: #markg  yes i want to delete the reference across all tables

Comment: use @ instead of # to reference a user :)... OK so if you can define foreign keys a certain way then you can let mysql do cascading deletes. Otherwise you will have to handle the three deletes in a transaction like a stored proc or something. Look at this:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE f.*, t.*, c.* FROM file f
JOIN topic t ON t.topic_id = f.topic_id
JOIN course c ON c.course_id = f.topic_id
WHERE f.topic_id = 28
```

This corresponds to the *Multiple-table syntax* in the MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/delete.html). It says:

> For the multiple-table syntax, DELETE deletes from each tbl_name the rows that satisfy the conditions.

The other way you can do this is to declare the columns as foreign keys to the parent table (I'm not sure what the parent/child relation is in your tables), and use the `ON DELETE CASCADE` option to the foreign keys. Then you can just delete the row from the parent table, and the related rows will be deleted automatically from the child tables. Note that foreign key enforcement requires that you use `InnoDB`, not `MyISAM`, as the database engine.

Comment: i want do some thing like that bt not woking...
DELETE f.*, t.*, c.* FROM course c, topic t, FILE f WHERE c.course_id = 26 AND (t.course_id =c.course_id AND (f.topic_id =t.topic_id))

Comment: I think that should work. Please make a sqlfiddle demonstrating the problem.

Comment: listen i have 3 tables in database course topic and file
i want delete course from php than how to delete complete course from table where topic have FK course id and files have FK topic id.

Comment: I understand what you have. I think my updated query should do what you want.

Comment: I want do something like this bt its not working... :(

DELETE f. *,
  t. *,
  c. *
FROM course c
  INNER JOIN topic t
    ON c.course_id = t.course_id
  INNER JOIN FILE f
    ON f.topic_id = t.topic_id
WHERE c.course_id = 26

Comment: I asked you to create a sqlfiddle so I can try to debug this. If you don't do that, I'm done with this question.