# Sql query for Cricket Manager

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an 2 Table

```
TEAMS -TeamId,TeamName,Country
Players-PlayerID,PlayerName,TotalScore,ToTalMatch,TotalRuns,AvgRunRate.
```

Now I want to create a table TEAMPLAYERS..which has to contain TEAMID,PlayerId...and if details is deleted in TEAMS,PLAYERS table..the data must be delete in THIRD TABLE..PLS HELP ME

Comment: Your question is unclear.  In fact, what is your question?

Comment: You should be able to use idea of foreign keys & cascade delete. i.e. Add teamId & playerId as foreign keys to your TeamPlayers table. Checkout this link http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-on-delete-cascade/

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you create a table with foreign key constraint with cascade delete.

```
CREATE TABLE TEAMPLAYERS (
.....
teamId int(11) NOT NULL,
playerId int(11) NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY(teamId)
REFERENCES TEAMS(teamId)
ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY(playerId)
REFERENCES PLAYERS(playerId)
ON DELETE CASCADE
.....
);
```

Note: ... are to be filled with other desired columns/constraints on TEAMPLAYERS table.
Additionally, refer to this other post which asks a similar question  [MySQL foreign key constraints, cascade delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914936/mysql-foreign-key-constraints-cascade-delete)

Hope this helps!