# Mysql database error - deleting records by a join query

Tags: mysql

I am trying to delete a single row from tbl_user and multiple rows from user_subscription_log, my join query is:

```
DELETE tbl_user, user_subscription_log
FROM tbl_user 
INNER JOIN user_subscription_log ON tbl_user.id = user_subscription_log.user_id
WHERE tbl_user.id='256'
```

The error returned is:

#1451 - Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`databasename`.`user_subscription_log`, CONSTRAINT `foreirgn_key_user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `tbl_user` (`id`))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's failing because a child record exists in `user_subscription_log` table and, no 'on delete' clause is set in Foreign key.

I'd execute two delete queries:

```
DELETE FROM user_subscription_log WHERE user_id = ?;

DELETE FROM tbl_user where id = ?;
```

Another option is to set 'on delete cascade' clause in the foreign key definition, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914936/mysql-foreign-key-constraints-cascade-delete).

Comment: I'd go with 'another option'