# Deleting records from a table with heirachial data

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables in an SQL database with fields as follows:

```
Table A: Key | Id1 | Name

Table B: Key | Id2 | Idx1 | Idx2 | Id1
```

Table B stores hierarchical data.  Field Id1 in Table B is linked back to Id1 in Table A with FKs set up such that deleting an item in Table 1 (say with Id1=1) will delete all of the items in Table B (with the same Id1) (ie. cascade).

What I want to do is that for a record in Table B that is deleted with a certain Id1 (as a consequence of a record with the same Id1 in Table A), all of the records in Table B with the same Id2 to be deleted too.

For example ...

```
Table A:
  1,1,A
  2,2,B
  3,3,C

Table B:
  1,1,0,0,1
  2,1,0,1,2
  3,1,0,2,3
  4,1,1,0,3
  5,1,1,1,2
  6,2,0,0,3
```

I now delete Item 1 (with Id1=1) from Table A such that:

```
Table A:
  2,2,B
  3,3,C

Table B:
  6,2,0,0,3
```

Can this be done automatically (eg. through triggers, etc.) in SQL or would I need to handle it 'manually' outside of the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you can take advantage of DELETE CASCADE feature of SQL Server.

If you have parent-child mapping between two tables in SQL you can delete child table records along with a single query to delete parent records.

To achieve this you will have to enable Delete cascading while establishing the relationship between the tables, following way:

```
CREATE TABLE products
( product_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  product_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  category VARCHAR(25)
);

CREATE TABLE inventory
( inventory_id INT PRIMARY KEY,
  product_id INT NOT NULL,
  quantity INT,
  min_level INT,
  max_level INT,
  CONSTRAINT fk_inv_product_id
    FOREIGN KEY (product_id)
    REFERENCES products (product_id)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Or if you have already defined the table data you can use the following method to do this:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.T2
   DROP CONSTRAINT FK_T1_T2   -- or whatever it's called

ALTER TABLE dbo.T2
   ADD CONSTRAINT FK_T1_T2_Cascade
   FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeID) REFERENCES dbo.T1(EmployeeID) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

or If you are using **MYSQL** (as it is not mentioned in question) you can follow the instructions on following StackOverflow post:

[MySQL foreign key constraints, cascade delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914936/mysql-foreign-key-constraints-cascade-delete)

Comment: I can see how this will delete the (single) record in Table B that has the same Id1.  What I'm wanting is for that record (Key=1) to be deleted AND THEN all of the records that have the same Id2 as that record in Table B to be deleted too (Key=2,3,4 and 5).  (I have updated the question as I left off the Key values to Table B.)

Comment: I can see how this will delete the (single) record in Table B that has the same Id1.  What I'm wanting is for that record (Key=1) to be deleted AND THEN all of the records that have the same Id2 as that record in Table B to be deleted too (Key=2,3,4 and 5).  (I have updated the question as I left off the Key values to Table B.)  If an element with Id1 is deleted in Table A (record i), then any element in Table B with the same Id1 is deleted (by cascading) (record ii) but so too shall any record in Table B that ha the same Id2 (as record ii).