# MySQL DELETE and many to many relationship

Tags: mysql, many-to-many

Given these schema

orders(order_number,created,status)
products(product_id,product_name)
orders_products(order_number,product_id,quantity)

If I would like to delete orders older than N days, I would have to delete also the records related to those orders in orders_products table.

How could I do this in a single query, without having to retrieve every single order_number, store them in the business logic and finally to run additional queries to clean the mapping table?

I don't have any FK

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL foreign key constraints, cascade delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914936/mysql-foreign-key-constraints-cascade-delete)

Comment: use `ON DELETE CASCADE` on pivot table in your DB structure, as mentioned by @mentallurg !!!

Answer (score -1):

This seems to work:

```
DELETE orders_products, orders 
FROM orders_products 
INNER JOIN orders 
ON orders_products.order_number = orders.order_number 
WHERE orders.created  < NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

Comment: Use cascade instead.