# delete from 2 table in sql that have a foreign key in other tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to delete (in one statement) rows from table **activities** *[eventid is PK]* and **bookings** *[studentid is FK and eventid is FK]*. I tried this :

```
delete bo from bookings as bo inner join activities as ac on ac.eventid=bo.eventid where bo.eventid=3
```

but it deletes row only in bookings.

what do I have to change?

Comment: You need `cascade` delete. Check --> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914936/mysql-foreign-key-constraints-cascade-delete

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reference all the tables you want to delete from:

```
delete bo, ac
    from bookings bo inner join
         activities ac
         on ac.eventid = bo.eventid
    where bo.eventid = 3;
```

This syntax is rather clearly explained in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html).

Typically, multi-table deletes can be replaced with cascading delete foreign key references.  You might be able to handle this just by properly defining your data model.