# on delete table with foreign key delete also the referenced table

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys

There is a way to delete the referenced record when I delete the row with the foreign key?
[This is my db's tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75gu0.png)
and I want delete the 3 record referenced of the table "righe" when I delete the record in table "cartelle"

Comment: No.  `ON DELETE CASCADE` allows deletion of the rows which reference a `primary key` when the row with that `primary key` value is deleted.  It would be odd to try to delete in the other direction.  Maybe you want to create a FK constraint in the other table.

Comment: Add the tables (in text form) to the question.  Explain the relationship and meaning of the tables and columns.  It's possible you just want the references to be reversed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL foreign key constraints, cascade delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914936/mysql-foreign-key-constraints-cascade-delete)

Answer (score 0):

Just add your reference in the other direction, like this:

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8c5b7eca1460084d297972633290210b)

```
-- cartelle (folder)

CREATE TABLE folders ( folder_id int primary key );

-- righe (rows, tied to a folder)

CREATE TABLE xrows   (
    row_id    int primary key
  , folder_id int
  , FOREIGN KEY (folder_id) REFERENCES folders (folder_id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);


INSERT INTO folders VALUES (1), (2), (3);

INSERT INTO xrows VALUES
    (1, 1)
  , (2, 1)
  , (3, 1)
  , (4, 2)
  , (5, 3)
  , (6, 2)
;
```

| row_id | folder_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 6 | 2 |

Now when we delete a `folder`, the corresponding `rows` will be deleted.

```
DELETE FROM folders WHERE folder_id = 1;
```

```
SELECT * FROM xrows;
```

The result:

| row_id | folder_id |
| --- | --- |
| 4 | 2 |
| 5 | 3 |
| 6 | 2 |