# SQL keeps returning Query failed and don't know where to go from here

Tags: sql, mysql

Trying to solve a Lab question but can't seem to figure it out. Error code keeps stating "Query failed: ERROR 3780 (HY000) at line 15: Referencing column 'HorseID' and referenced column 'ID' in foreign key constraint 'lessonschedule_ibfk_1' are incompatible."

Here are the directions incase you need a better idea of what I am trying to do.

"The database contains a Horse table, with columns:

- ID - integer, primary key
- RegisteredName - variable-length string

The database contains a Student table, with columns:

- ID - integer, primary key
- FirstName - variable-length string
- LastName - variable-length string

Create a third table, named LessonSchedule, with columns:

- HorseID - integer with range 0 to 65 thousand, not NULL, foreign key references Horse(ID)
- StudentID - integer with range 0 to 65 thousand, foreign key references Student(ID)
- LessonDateTime - date/time, not NULL
- Primary key is (HorseID, LessonDateTime)

If a row is deleted from Horse, the rows with the same horse ID should be deleted from LessonSchedule automatically.

If a row is deleted from Student, the same student IDs should be set to NULL in LessonSchedule automatically."

```
CREATE TABLE Horse (
    ID              SMALLINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    RegisteredName  VARCHAR(15),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

CREATE TABLE Student (
    ID             SMALLINT UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT,
    FirstName      VARCHAR(20),
    LastName        VARCHAR(30),
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);

-- Your SQL statements go here 
CREATE TABLE LessonSchedule (
HorseID SMALLINT NOT NULL,
StudentID SMALLINT,
LessonDateTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
Primary Key (HorseID, StudentID, LessonDateTime),
Foreign Key (HorseID) REFERENCES Horse(ID),
Foreign Key (StudentID) REFERENCES Student(ID)
);
```

So far, I've tried messing with the foreign key constraints but have been unsuccessful. I'm not really sure what to do at all.

Comment: Side note: seems like it should be `Primary Key (HorseID, LessonDateTime)` Also you need `CASCADE` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914936/mysql-foreign-key-constraints-cascade-delete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE LessonSchedule (
HorseID SMALLINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
StudentID SMALLINT UNSIGNED,
LessonDateTime DATETIME NOT NULL,
Primary Key (HorseID, StudentID, LessonDateTime),
Foreign Key (HorseID) REFERENCES Horse(ID),
Foreign Key (StudentID) REFERENCES Student(ID)
);
```

The reason is that the constraints are different.You have set UNSIGNED on the IDs of the two primary tables.The fields in the associated tables below also need to be consistent.

Comment: Thanks for this! Still some things I have to tweak but the Query is at least going through now